# How to remove strange div called dp_swf_engine from html page?

Tags: html, flash

On [my site](http://keessonnema.nl), I recently found a strange new automatically generated div. when I look at it in development tools in chrome I says:

```
<div id="dp_swf_engine" style="position: absolute; width: 1px; height: 1px;"><embed style="width: 1px; height: 1px;" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.ajaxcdn.org/swf.swf" width="1" height="1" id="_dp_swf_engine" name="_dp_swf_engine" bgcolor="#336699" quality="high" allowscriptaccess="always"></div>
```

I really don't know what it is, and where it's coming from.

Comment: Can you not just go into your code and remove it?

Comment: No, I don't see it anywhere. Only if I inspect it.

Comment: I have similar problem but along with this div a strange iframe is also added. And it's not on chrome only but also on firefox. Iframe is added on both browsers but the design breaks on firefox. A white empty line is added at the bottom while on chrome the design doesn't break. Can anyone please tell me what might be causing this?

Comment: I'm having this too now! On every website, with 0 extensions enabled, in incognito mode. It might be because I download FileZilla from SourceForge and got forced a stupid 'installer' with a bunch op options and ads and crap.

Comment: Try looking in your programs, all programs you don't know have to be deleted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I already had a similar problem and the div came from a chrome extension, check which extension can modify your pages.

Comment: This was the problem! I had (unwanted) installed an extension called savanshare ?? this added the div automatically. thanks for pointing me to it :)

Answer (score 2):

- Sometimes it will be automatically adding from your web hosting
  server
- If you are using an external plugins it will be coming from it
- I could see you are using google fonts.... Try removing and check your site
- You can run your website on a local server...

To hide the DIV, Try adding this css:

```
<style type="text/css">
dp_swf_engine {
 display:none;
}
</style>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the document ready event :

```
var element = document.getElementById("dp_swf_engine");
document.body.removeChild(element)
```

if your div is directly in your body element else, find his parent for call removeChildFunction...

I hope that help !

Comment: This does not fix my problem. It only hides it.

Comment: it would be deleted... so maybe it loaded on document ready too and this function can't works...